# flow text around a transparent png with css/jquery/anything

Tags: jquery, css, image, transparency

For now, i have:

```
<img style="float:right;" src="/path/to/image.png">
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```

Which nicely sets the image right and the text around it. Is it, however, possible to 'flow' text around the actual contents of an png image, ignoring the transparancy?

It now looks like this:

[image: before]

I would like it to look like this:

### [image: after]

Possibilities i see:

```
1) Manually add breaks
```

Almost impossible for dynamic content;

```
2) Have php add breaks after a set number of characters
```

Very complex, and it would need to be determined for every image;

```
3) Another way someone here knows about
```

Does anyone have any experience with situations like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only conceivable way I could think of for wrapping text around images without hardcoding anything is to enlist the help of jQuery. There is a plugin called [jQSlickWrap](http://www.jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/) - it might be the solution that you're looking for. However, it does require HTML5 support on the browser's behalf, so it will not work for IE users as of yet.

Comment: I do feel sympathetic about IE users, especially those stuck behind corporate restrictions that are forced to use it :/ 

However, I would see this as progressive enhancement - while IE users will be stuck without beautiful dynamic text wrapping around the image, the image still floats properly so that's still acceptable. We should not penalize users of modern, standards compliant browsers by watering down our design to fit IE6 though :)

Answer (score 6):

The "right" way to do this is [CSS3 Shapes](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2013/03/27/freeing-the-floats-of-the-future-from-the-tyranny-of-the-rectangle/) / [Exclusions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-exclusions/) (shape-outside/inside, etc.).

Unfortunately as of April 2013 these have not yet been widely implemented. Chrome/Webkit has a test in its canary builds. Perhaps Mozilla will follow on.

Comment: THIS! I’ve been waiting for this since 1999! It’s the main leftover reason why HTML/CSS isn’t yet usable for proper DTP.

Comment: As of March 2016 it is still not usable: http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20shapes%7Cexclusion

Answer (score 0):

Any automatic breaking point detection would involve very complex edge detection, text-metrics and flow computation which are TOO complicated for little gain.

The only feasible way that comes to my mind is to manually approximate the image with a few floating boxes (DIVs) that overlay the image (using HTML+CSS).

Answer (score -1):

This is definitely possible. You just need to create blank elements with a height equal to the line-height of text and the width of where you want the text to break. Then float these elements in your text, with a `clear: both` CSS style and have your image be absolutely positioned with a z-index under the text.

Comment: Do you have an example?