# wrap text around an image in html and css

Tags: html, css

i have the following :
http://prntscr.com/ebu70b 
i am trying to make the text wrap around the globe, so it is about 20px away from it on each line like this :
http://prntscr.com/ebu9ef

```
<div class="section">
                <img src="images/globe.png" class="leftimage">
                <div class="smtitle righttext">Title</div>
                <p class="righttext">
                        <!--This is just lorem ipsum no need to scroll-->Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis tincidunt leo. Maecenas malesuada tincidunt arcu, vel tristique quam tincidunt sit amet. Ut nisl risus, fermentum at metus a, sodales porta dolor. Curabitur posuere ligula a lacus iaculis, vel lacinia metus porttitor. Nunc iaculis, ipsum quis tristique semper, tortor tellus lobortis dui, id hendrerit nisi enim sit amet libero. Morbi vehicula porta lectus a varius. Pellentesque vestibulum fermentum turpis et ullamcorper. Curabitur venenatis lacus nec bibendum malesuada. Phasellus mollis in turpis vel tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eget luctus nisi. Nulla odio quam, hendrerit vitae cursus vitae, gravida at sapien. Aenean ullamcorper elit ligula, id molestie metus bibendum non.
                </p>
</div>
```

this is the css:

```
.section{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
.righttext{
    padding:0 15px;
    float:right;
    text-align:left;
    width:70%;
}
.rightimage{
    float:right;
    width:30%;
}
.leftimage{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}
.lefttext{
    padding:0 15px;
    float:left;
    text-align:right;
    width:70%;
}
```

I have no idea how to do this, i realize that i will need a round image for this most likely, i will take care of that if needed

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491691/flow-text-around-a-transparent-png-with-css-jquery-anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to **Dudley Storey**

You need shape-outside: circle();

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
#circle-shape-example { 
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif; 
  margin: 2rem; 
}
#circle-shape-example p { 
  line-height: 1.8; 
}
#circle-shape-example .curve { 
  width: 33%; height: auto;
  min-width: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin-right:2rem; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-shape-outside:circle();
  shape-outside:circle();
}
```

```html
<div id="circle-shape-example">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/kiwifruit-on-a-plate.jpg" alt="A photograph of sliced kiwifruit on a while plate" class="curve">
  
  <h1>KiwiFruit</h1>
  <p>This is kiwifruit: originally called “yang tao”, “melonette” or Chinese gooseberry. Cultivated in its fuzzy variety from Chinese imports, the fruit proved popular with American military servicemen stationed in New Zealand during World War II, with commercial export to the United States starting after the end of the war. In California, the fruit was rebranded as “kiwifruit” due to its resemblance to New Zealand’s national bird. However, it is not a “kiwi”, which is also the demonym for native New Zealanders. Saying “I’m going to eat a kiwi” implies that you are either a cannibal or planning to dine on an endangered flightless bird.
</div>
```